# SSO login fails occasionally

Tags: kubernetes, spring-security

I have a spring boot app that is responsible for authenticating users through an external identity provider. After successful authentication the springboot app redirects the user through 2 redirects to the UI service with the access token (UI is run as a separate service). Now the springboot app responsible for performing backend authentication is running on a kubernetes cluster with 2 replica sets. Sometimes on login, after coming back from the external identity provider I run into a whitelabel error. I think this is because the login request may have been sent from one instance and then come back to another instance and login flow may have been disrupted. How to ensure that a request is sent from one instance and completed from the same instance in the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: You can't guarantee that in general.  There's a real case where one replica handles a first request, and then is terminated for some reason, and another replica needs to handle the rest of the session.  Consider using some sort of Spring Data store to persist data where it can be read across all of the replicas.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did. Configured spring to use mongodb for cache storing for duration of time.